# Why is a source required when using 'runCommand'?

Tags: nix

I'm having trouble using the function `runCommand`, it was my understanding that it would not require a source to be run but when I run the code:

```
(import <nixpkgs> {}).runCommand "my-test" {} ''
     mkdir $out
     cat << EOF > $out/my-test
       echo Hello    
     EOF
     chmod +x $out/my-test
''
```

I'm faced with this error

```
unpacking sources
variable $src or $srcs should point to the source
```

I've then tried adding `unpackPhase = "true";` which brought me an error about an obviously non-existent Makefile.

It seems that it's trying to run all the phase when building a normal derivation.

I am using the wrong function for the job or I am missing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Just a file `foo.nix` with those contents and running `nix-build foo.nix` will build it just fine.

Comment: After @SilvanMosberger comment I have tested it in a docker container and it actually worked. When I was first testing it, I was under debian, is there any setting that I could have changed that would cause this kind of behavior?